# Console.readPassword() creates infinite loop in java

Tags: java, passwords

I am working on a banking program through the console. I wanted to hide the password as the user enters it.

I created my own method that reads the passwords and returns a String using the readPassword() method in the Console class:

```
/**
 * Reads Password without allowing the console to show the characters 
    while the user is typing the password.
 * @return
 */
public String readPass(){
    String pass = "";
    Console cnsl = System.console();
    if(cnsl!=null){
        char[] pword = cnsl.readPassword();
        for(char c: pword){
            pass+=c;
        }
        return pass;
    }
    return "";
}
```

The method is called from another class:

```
/**
 * Asks the user to enter their password. Then checks if the password is right.
 * @param u
 */
public void checkPassword(User u){
    boolean pa = false;
    do{
        System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
        //String pword = in.next();
        String pword = b.readPass();
        pa = u.checkPassword(pword);
        if(pa){
            System.out.println("\nLogin Successful...");
            System.out.println("\nWelcome "+ u.getName() + "!");
            enterAccount(u);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That is the incorrect password. Please try again.\n");
        }
    }while(!pa);
}
```

The moment the password is prompted, the else block is executed and the result is an infinite loop.

Comment: @AhsN Why should he do this? It will be executed as the first statements in the loop.

Comment: @SpecialK Maybe your method `User.checkPassword(String)` always returns `false`? Additionally, what happens if you don't have a console? You will not be given the opportunity to enter anything, but your `readPass` method simply returns an empty string (always). Maybe this is your inifinite loop?

Comment: Are you sure checkPassword works ok?

Comment: you don't need a do while loop in a password checking mechanism, or do you? password checking only need to be done one time per password and than its done, right?

Comment: An infinite loop would occur, if `cnsl` is `null`.

Comment: is the program always going to the else block? regardless the password match?

Comment: did you do any debugging?

Comment: @Blip: do we have a generic "How to debug in Java" question and answer somewhere?

Comment: You have problem with `pa = u.checkPassword(pword);` which always returns false. Add some syso to debug, rather than getting more puzzled.

Comment: @Thomas I wanted to know if OP has done some debugging or not to get some debugging informations

Comment: @Blip: If OP does not know how to debug at all (which is not so unlikely), providing a link on how to debug might increase OPs ability to debug in the order of magnitudes.

Comment: You should not use the password as string. It is a char array for a securty reason. You should check it as array and then overwrite it with other characters so an attacker can't read it from memory.

Comment: I just did some debugging and the csnl variable in the readPass() method is null when I call System.console as @Christopher said. The checkPassword() works fine because the program previously worked fine with Scanner input (you can see I commented out that line), except for the fact that the while the user is typing, characters are not hidden.

Comment: Also I'm doing this in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your console is null, the infinite loop can occur.There is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429) in eclipse which causes npe for System.console.

Try using Scanner for testing code.

Please read this [explanation](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.in/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html)

[From console java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)
Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.

Also instead of repeatedly concatinating characters, you can convert character array to string as `pass = new String(pword)`.

If you want to test from IDE, try using scanner(password will be visible while typing) or you can create a small `JDialog` and embed a [JPasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) inside it

Comment: This would be the case only if the OP is not running from the command prompt. But if he is running from the command prompt then what could be the reason?

Comment: I am using eclipse and its console, and previously everything worked fine when I used scanner, except that the password was not hidden. How do I make the password hidden if I can't utilize System.console?

Comment: This is definitely the problem, as I realize after debugging, but what would be an equivalent workaround?

Comment: Check in the run configuration->Common Tab->Allocate console (necessary for input) is checked.Also try running the class file directly from Win/Linux console